# Problem running Shell commands, it just stucks

Tags: magento2

When trying to run even simple command like:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

It just stucks.
Though some of the command like

```
php bin/magento cache:disable
php bin/magento cache:enable
php bin/magento index:reindex
```

do run.
but for the commands, which stucks, when I see the server load keeps increasing to staggering number like form 1% it goes up to 35%

I am not able to find out where is the issue.
in the same installation, I was able to run these commands.

update:if I run the command with `memory_limit=-1`
the script never seems to end, but if I limit it like
`memory_limit=10G'
I get this error

`Running schema recurring...PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 10737418240 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /web/vendor/magento/framework/App/State.php on line 152`

the relevant code on line 152 reads like this:

```
 /**
     * Get area code
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function getAreaCode()
    {
        if (!isset($this->_areaCode)) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Area code is not set')
            );
        }
        return $this->_areaCode;
    }
```

and the module which seems responsible for the error, the code looks like this:

```
class AppState
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
 */
protected $state;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\State $state) {
    $this->state = $state;
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isFrontendArea()
{
    try {
        if ($this->state->getAreaCode() == Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        /* Area is not initialized. Do nothing. */
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

I think this info is enough for any expert to find the issue I am facing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be lack of available memory.

Many of the magento2 cli commands incur heavy cpu and memory usage.
The reindexing in particular is a heavy duty process.

Try running the cli commands with unlimited memory.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If even that stalls it means you need to allocate more memory to your vm.

In my local devbox I have 2 GB allocated, and I have to run the cli
with the "-d memory_limit=-1" option every time otherwise it freezes/crashes.

Comment: Hi - indexer:reindex command is working fine. The problem I am facing is with other commands.

Comment: Hi still have issues. don't know why. but there is some success with your suggestion. As regarding the memory available I have 16GB as Dedicated server.

Comment: You might be able to improve the reindexing process by indicating specific indexes, as running the command without any arguments runs all indexers.